# How to find to bug in a debugger on codeblocks with a C code?

Tags: c, genetic-algorithm

I am development a code with about  Genetic Algorithm that is find out a minimun spanning tree, all this in C. CodeBlocks debuger help me to find out the error that I have, but it catch me a error in a line but I dont know that happens in this line.

```
matrizAux[mutador.genes[i].v1][posicionesMatriz[mutador.genes[i].v1]]=mutador.genes[i].v2;
```

Debuger say me that is Segment default, but I dont know the error.

My function code where debuger catch the error is following:

```
Cromosoma *mutacion(Cromosoma mutador, double probMutacion,int numGenes,Cromosoma *nuevaPoblacion, int posicion, Gen *setGenes,int numAristas,int numVertices){
int numGenesMutar=(numVertices-1)*probMutacion;
int indice,cont=0,listo,indiceGenes,i;
int *indicesMutaciones=calloc(numGenesMutar,sizeof(*indicesMutaciones));
int *visitados=NULL;
visitados=calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*visitados));
//printf("Numero de genes a mutar : %i\n",numGenesMutar);
while(cont<numGenesMutar){
    indice=rand()%numGenesMutar;
    if(indicesMutaciones[indice]!=0)
        continue;
    indicesMutaciones[indice]=1;
    cont++;
    int **matrizAux=NULL;
    matrizAux=inicializarMatriz(matrizAux,numVertices);
    int *posicionesMatriz=calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*posicionesMatriz));
    //Generando mi matriz auxiliar
    mutador.fitnessValue=0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < numVertices-1 ; i++){
        if(i==indice)
            continue;
        //printf("%i\n",mutador.genes[i].v1);
        matrizAux[mutador.genes[i].v1][posicionesMatriz[mutador.genes[i].v1]]=mutador.genes[i].v2;
        matrizAux[mutador.genes[i].v2][posicionesMatriz[mutador.genes[i].v2]]=mutador.genes[i].v1;
        posicionesMatriz[mutador.genes[i].v1]++;
        posicionesMatriz[mutador.genes[i].v2]++;
        mutador.fitnessValue+=mutador.genes[i].peso;
    }
    Gen genAux;
    while(1){
       indiceGenes=rand()%numAristas;
       genAux=setGenes[indiceGenes];
        listo=1;
       valido(matrizAux,numVertices,genAux.v1,genAux.v2,&listo,visitados);
       memset(visitados,0,numVertices*sizeof(*visitados));
       if(listo==1)
        break;
    }
    free(posicionesMatriz);
    mutador.genes[indice]=genAux;
    mutador.fitnessValue+=mutador.genes[indice].peso;
}
nuevaPoblacion[posicion]=mutador;
free(indicesMutaciones);
free(visitados);
//printf("Mutador con fitness : %i\n", mutador.fitnessValue);
return (Cromosoma *)nuevaPoblacion;
```

}

Comment: Use `valgrind` to detect your invalid memory read/writes. Valgrind is integrated in codeblock.

Comment: compile with gdb symbols enabled setup ulimit -c to drop a core file, reproduce the problem, then have a look at the backtrace. The backtrace may show a good amount of detail on variable contents. However if not you may need to put a breakpoint on the line before or step through it in gdb.

Comment: "Segmentation fault" commonly means that some memory is tried to be accessed that can't be accessed. You may have out-of-bounds accesses or NULL pointers.